# CAML query join and sort by column of projected fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
query.Query =<Where>
 <IsNotNull>
  <FieldRef Name='Product' />
 </IsNotNull>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
 <FieldRef Name='CountryCode4' Ascending='FALSE' />
</OrderBy>

query.Join = <Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='ProductList'>
 <Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='Product' RefType='Id' />
  <FieldRef List='ProductList' Name='ID' />
 </Eq>
</Join>
<Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='AuthorisationLookupList'>
 <Eq>
  <FieldRef List='ProductList' Name='MarketingAuthorisationLookup' RefType='Id' />
  <FieldRef List='AuthorisationLookupList' Name='ID' />
 </Eq>
</Join>
<Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='AuthorisationStatusLookupList'>
 <Eq>
  <FieldRef List='AuthorisationLookupList' Name='AuthorisationStatusLookup' RefType='Id' />
  <FieldRef List='AuthorisationStatusLookupList' Name='ID' />
```

When applying sorting the column "CountryCode" is empty and sorting has not taken place. If, however, I sort by the column "Title" everything works fine. Would anybody have a clue as to why and if what I am trying to achieve is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafal,

I know this question is quite old, but just came across this post.. If we look at following link, which explains the Limitations of CAML Joins:
[JOINS AND PROJECTIONS IN SHAREPOINT 2010](http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2012/12/joins-and-projections-in-sharepoint-2010.html)

It says:

> **Limitations**
>
> - There is no way to leverage joins and projections in a view through the UI.  CAML must be written.  Few things are more badass than CAMLs,
>     but they're often hairy.  (Get it...? Maaan I crack myself up)
> - Joins can only be defined on lookup columns
> - Projected fields cannot be used to sort or group in the view
> - Dynamic sorting and filtering in listview webparts is also not supported
> - Projected columns do not show up correctly in datasheet view, or when exported to Excel

Point 3 explains why your query is not working.

Comment: Ha! Thank you Arsalan for taking the time to answer that old question.