# CSOM Join with CAML query raise exception

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, caml-query

I am trying to retrieve all `Customer Contracts` which `Customer Master` has `Procurement Relevant = True`

I used CSOM to communicate with SharePoint 2010 to retrieve list items and used CAML query to filter and join lists .

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Customer Contracts");
var itemColl = await Task.Run<ListItemCollection>(() =>
                {
                    CamlQuery query =//CAMEL query showed below 

                    ListItemCollection coll = list.GetItems(query);
                    clientContext.Load(coll);
                    // Execute the query to the server
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    return coll;
                });
```

It raised the following exception when query executed

> Exception :
>   ( Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
>     Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
>     ServerErrorCode=-2147024809
>     ServerErrorTypeName=System.ArgumentException )

Check the following CAML query :

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="CustomerProcurementRelevant" />
                <Value Type="String">True</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <Joins>
        <Join Type="INNER" ListAlias="Customer Master">
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Customer_x0020_ID" RefType="Id" />
                <FieldRef List="Customer Master" Name="ID" />
            </Eq>
        </Join>
    </Joins>
    <ProjectedFields>
        <Field Name="CustomerProcurmentRelevant" Type="Lookup" List="Customer Master" ShowField="Procurement_x0020_Relevant" />
    </ProjectedFields>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified" /><FieldRef Name="Customer_x0020_ID" /><FieldRef Name="Title" /><FieldRef Name="ES_x0020_Service_x0020_Segment" />
        <FieldRef Name="ADE_x002f_ADM" /><FieldRef Name="Account_x0020_Controlling" /><FieldRef Name="Contract_x0020_terminated" /><FieldRef Name="Country" />
        <FieldRef Name="CustomerProcurmentRelevant" />
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit>999999</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a `SPQuery` object to the `GetItems` method.
In the query attribute you have to put just the `<Query>` tag.
Use:

```
SPQUery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "" //your <Query>...</Query> tag
//for all your view field
query.ViewFields ="<FieldRef Name='ID'/>"
```

To specify the row limit use:

```
query.RowLimit = 100;
```

To specify the scope:

```
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\""
```

To specify Joins:

```
query.Joins = "";
```

and

```
query.ProjectedFields="";
```

Take a look to these links:

[JOINS AND PROJECTIONS IN SHAREPOINT 2010](http://sharepointificate.blogspot.it/2012/12/joins-and-projections-in-sharepoint-2010.html)
[CAML query join](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74775/caml-query-join-and-sort-by-column-of-projected-fields)

Comment: Thanks @NK SP for your reply but why I need to re assign view fields and row limit as I did assign them in CAML query showed . Regarding links you showed I think these limitation not applied with my case . By the ways this code worked successfully before but without last update which is join and projected fields .

Comment: Even if the question is old, he has not to pass an `SPQuery`, since he is using `CSOM` and not the server api. `CSOM` has no `Query`, `ViewAttributes`, `Joins` and `ViewAllFields` properties.